# fortran project in eclipse parallel oxygen is not created

Tags: eclipse, parallel-processing, fortran

I am trying to import a fortran code that utilises mpi for parallel computing. 
I installed eclipse parallel oxygen, but when I try to create a project (so that I can later import my code), it just does not create it.

Here is what I do. Right click on project explorer, go to new -> Fortran Project -> Empty Project.  I then choose a name. The finish bottom is now on, but when I press it, nothing happens (I can see a small red square appears for a second and then it is gone, suggesting that the operation is not allowed, but that is all).

I was wondering if anyone has any clue what is wrong here.

Thanks